# Как найти сумму BigInteger?

Tags: java

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как же всё найти сумму цифр `BigInteger`?
Или я что-то делаю не так?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("print variable x = ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = in.nextInt();
    if (x < 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("variable x suppose to be more than 0");
    }
    BigInteger fact = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
    for (int i = 2; i <= x; i++) {
        fact = fact.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i)) ;
    }
    System.out.println("fact is = " + fact);

    long sum = 0;
        do {
            sum = sum + (fact % 10);//здесь начинаются все проблемы т.к. тип BigInteger не поддаётся обычным арифметическим операторам
        }
        while ((fact /= 10) != 0);
    System.out.println("sum of factorial is = " + sum);
}
```

Comment: То есть - ваша проблема сводится к "как получить `BigInteger % 10`"?

Answer (score 1):

Может я не так понял проблему, но:

```
sum = sum + fact.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(10)).longValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

Работая вперемежку с **BigInteger** и **Long** вы рискуете потерять точность вычислений.

**BigInteger.longValue()** - возвращает первые 64 бита - потеря информации.

Если вы не можете объяснить зачем вам **BigInteger** используйте в данном случае **Long**.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        BigInteger a = new BigInteger(scanner.nextLine());
        BigInteger b =  new BigInteger(scanner.nextLine());
        System.out.println(a.add(b));

    }
}
```